# map reduce word count example doesn't work

Tags: mapreduce, word-count

I try to implement the word count example by myself, here's my implementation of the mapper:

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Text word = new Text();     
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(word, new IntWritable(1));
        }
    }
}
```

and reducer:

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext())
            sum += values.next().get();
    context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
```

but the output I get for executing this code looks like the output of mapper only, for example, if the input is "hello world hello", the output would be

```
hello 1
hello 1
world 1
```

I also use combiner between mapping and reducing. Can anyone explain me what's wrong with this code?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace you reduce method with this one:

```
        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, java.lang.Iterable<IntWritable> values, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>.Context context) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable value : values) {
                sum += value.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
```

So bottom line is you're not overriding the correct method. The @Override helps with this kind of errors.

Also make sure you set Reduce.class as reduce class and not Reducer.class !

;)
HTH
Johannes

Comment: Thanks for this. I was stuck on this problem for a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to play with args of reduce method while overriding than alternate solution can be:

```
@Override
protected void reduce(Object key, Iterable values, Context context) throws 
IOException, InterruptedException {

 int sum = 0;
 Iterable<IntWritable> v = values;
 Iterator<IntWritable> itr = v.iterator();

 while(itr.hasNext()){
    sum += itr.next().get();
 }

 context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
}
```